# Load image called with pushbutton to the pushbutton's background

Tags: image, matlab, button, background

Prior to answering, please keep in mind that I am totally new in Matlab.

Hey guys I’m trying to load a picture on a button when it is clicked.

Once I've loaded the .jpg image to the push button the image is very large, behind the button, set like a background image; How do I resize it to fit it in the push button (better if possible to set as the background image of the pushbutton)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `imresize`  to fit the image to the size of your button.

Example:

```
buttonWidth  = 100; %in Pixels
buttonHeight = 100;
imPad        = 10;  %A little bit of padding

imData = imread('yourImage.jpg');  %Read your image
imSmall= imresize(imData , [buttonWidth   buttonHeight]-imPad); %Resize it.

% Place it on the button
h=uicontrol('style','pushbutton', 'units','pixels',...
            'position',[50 50 buttonWidth buttonHeight],...
            'cdata',imSmall)
```